# Rich Text component in AEM 6.3 touch ui

Tags: touch, aem

I knew about xtype richtext for classic ui.
I am working more on touch ui these days and would like to have a rich text component in cq:dialog touch dialog.

Could anyone point me to an example with explanation about the rich text component in aem 6.3 touch ui?

I was looking at the [example](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/text/v2/text) I do not understand rtePlugins node in  _cq_editConfig.xml and I assume basic richtext functionality is provided by _cq_dialog content.xml

What is the different between [example2](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/text/v1/text)
and [example](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/text/v2/text)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rtePlugins node lists configurations for enabled plugins in the RTE. You can use either examples you have in your post to achieve the rich text functionality you are after.

If you are interested in a different form of RTE, checkout this CKEditor widget I built a while back: https://github.com/ahmed-musallam/aem-ckeditor-widget